# d3-transition v2: Error: transition 1 not found

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to migrate an existing component from `d3-transition` v1.3.2 to v2.0.0 but get the following error at runtime: `Error: transition 1 not found`

My code is the following:

```
const t = transition();

const section = this.svg.selectAll('.area').data([data], (d) => {
    return this.y(d.value);
});

section
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .merge(section)
      .transition(t)
      .duration(this.animationDuration)
      .ease(easeLinear)
      .attr('class', 'area')
      .attr('d', line);
```

If I remove the transition, the charts are rendered correctly. I understand I should probably  plug somewhere a `selectAll('....')` but I am unsure at which stage of the chain and what to select.

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I faced a dead end therefore I opened an [issue](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition/issues/116) which, turned out to be a support request, my bad .

There were two things to fix in my solution:

1. not inheriting from the transition `t` because it was not needed
2. modifying my import `import {transition} from 'd3-transition';` to `import 'd3-transition';` otherwise the transition without `t` would be not found

Applied to my question's code:

```
import 'd3-transition'; // <--- 1. import modiffied
 
const section = this.svg.selectAll('.area').data([data], (d) => {
    return this.y(d.value);
});

section
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .merge(section)
      .transition() // <--- 2. not inheriting t
      .duration(this.animationDuration)
      .ease(easeLinear)
      .attr('class', 'area')
      .attr('d', line);
```

Answer (score 13):

In my case the problem was with transition reusing. I thought it can be declared once and used over and over. **Transitions are not reusable and a factory must be used.**

When a transition ends it becomes unavailable. `transition` function(the one in chain) in such case used to load default transition if the one in parameter was invalid, now it errors out.

The correct solution now is to use a transition factory

```
// there's nothing wrong with this import
import {transition} from 'd3-transition';
function getTransition() {
    return transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .ease(easeLinear)
}

const section = this.svg.selectAll('.area').data([data], (d) => {
    return this.y(d.value);
});

section
      .enter()
      .append('path')
      .merge(section)
      .transition(getTransition())
      // .duration(this.animationDuration) // now duration
      // .ease(easeLinear)
      .attr('class', 'area')
      .attr('d', line);
```

Comment: https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join
This example does re-use a transition but I get the 'not found' error if I re-use a transition in my code, and your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: @YooMatsuo in older versions is was "possible" to re-use transitions. Why? Because after a transition was used and became null there was a mechanism to fallback to a default transition. That could cause the code to misbehave unexpectedly. Now it errors out to make sure the code is written correctly.